# Tutorial about how to use Reverse Image Search

Tags: discussion

I wrote a full tutorial on how to use Reverse Image Search to identify an anime beacause a lot of askers simply can use RIS to find the anime but they don't know how, here are some examples:

- [1](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6112/what-is-the-source-of-this-anime-image-with-girls-in-towels)
- [2](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/can-you-help-me-identify-this-anime)
- [3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/black-haired-girl-transforming-to-red-haired-girl-with-a-teddy-bear)
- [4](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/where-does-this-tattooed-anime-manga-character-originate)

I intended to post it on the anime.SE site, but thought it may get closed or removed so I thought to talk about it in the meta.

Comment: I think it would be welcome to post the tutorial here on meta. I'm not sure it belongs on the main site though, since it's not really about anime or manga but about Google's image search.

Comment: I agree with Logan M. Post it on meta, and then people can comment with a link to it when somebody comes by with a reverse-image-searchable question.

Comment: You might think of posting the question on [web apps SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) which has [a few](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1485/55194) [related questions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51274/55194)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's a great thing you chose to get it to meta, instead of directly posting it on the site.

Second, I believe that you can phrase it as a question/answer pair, and post it here on meta. It will be, eventually, tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and then referenced whenever needed.

Comment: OK, I'll post it as soon as possible.